# Virtual Studio loads Unity Scripts as "Miscellaneous Files"

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywEeI.png)

Tried to connect VS with Unity but did not get full functionality. Also couldn't download unity directly from unity hub, which prevents the addition of modules.

I have tried the standard solutions: added Virtual Studio Tools, added Visual Studio to External Script Editor, etc. I can open scripts in VS but don't get Intellisense or any other tools.

Some additional info: I manually installed VS because the Hub didn't work at all for downloads. Also, after adding the VS External Tool to Unity, I don't get the Generate csproj checkbox, in fact nothing changes. See attached screenshot.

Thanks.

Comment: did you follow instructions on how to link them? did you check you have the package, is it setup correctly in the setings? did you install the correct models in visual studio?